# Run unity exe file in a small window instead of fullscreen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a game and exported it to and EXE file but when I run it, it runs in full screen! How do I make it so that it runs in a window?

Comment: [PlayerSettings -> Resolution and Presentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html#Resolution) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't change it after you exported it. In the Unity Editor, go to Edit > Project Settings > Player and then scroll down to Resolution and Presentation. Then under Resolution, change the full-screen mode to match your needs.